# K235 Keyboard not working on Manjaro but mouse does & both work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: manjaro, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, logitech-keyboard

My keyboard - K235 Logitech - will not work on Manjaro MATE, but the mouse works flawlessly. The keyboard works perfectly fine on Ubuntu 20.04, so its not the keyboard itself. I'm not sure what input to check - the Logitech Unifying Receiver was detected and works fine, so I'm pretty sure its a driver issue. What would I need to do to diagnose and fix the issue? Apologies for a lack of information, I will post more when I find out what I need to look for.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has resolved itself because Manjaro... doesn't have xorg-xinput installed by default. Found this out trying to run xinput list. Installing it fixed the issue.